# Как получить данные в Base64 из данных файла input form?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, base64

Как получить данные в Base64 из данных файла input form?

Вот так мы читаем данные файла из input form, как можно получить **Base64** из `fileList`?

**HTML**

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" id="uploadform">
        <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" name="file"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"/><br/><br/>
</form>
```

---

**JS**

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById("uploadBtn");
    inputElement.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);

function handleFiles() {

        var fileList = this.files; 
}
```

Comment: Зачем может пригодится base64 файла на клиентской строне?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно прочитать файл с помощью `FileReader()`, и взять результат в Base64 из поля `target.result` результата.

```js
function handleFiles() {
  var reader = new FileReader(),
    input = document.getElementById('input').files[0],
    output = document.getElementById('output');
  reader.addEventListener("loadend", function(result) {
    output.innerHTML = result.target.result;
  }, false);
  reader.readAsDataURL(input);
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="file" onchange="handleFiles()" />
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Как считаете, это кроссбраузерный вариант?

Comment: @gilo1212 , Вот [тут](http://caniuse.com/#search=FileReader) посмотрите

Comment: @UserName Понятнентько. Спасибо. Вообщем IE 9  и меньше не поддерживает.